# OSX 10 - Apache refusing to work - how to debug or start from scratch

Tags: php, macos, apache

I've been using Apache to serve my dev sites on my local machine.

I've been using Apache with passenger for my rails work and setting up custom vhosts for my php work.

I **did not do the initial set up** on my machine. So I'm not exactly sure how it was configured.   I was trying to tweak some settings on the weekend and seem to have broken it all.

I think I deleted a default.conf alias file from the root of my apache2 folder.

I'm completely at a loss at how to fix this, so I have a few questions.

How can I start to debug? Where should I look for errors?

How can I just reset to it's initial state? if I do this, could you point me to a tutorial on how to set up  php/vhosts dev without having to use mamp.

Help is much appreciated - I've been pulling my hair out for 2 days with this one.

Comment: Do you start apache via command line (`/usr/sbin/apachectl start`)? If so, does it print any errors? Can you look into `/var/log/apache2/error_log` for any errors? (I'm assuming you're using the apache installation that came with Mac OS X, not some custom build one) Apache's main config file resides at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and references (via lines starting with "Include", at the end of the file) some additional configuration files in `/etc/apache2/extra`. Can you check if any of those are missing?

Comment: thanks simon - I get no errors when I start from cmd line. My error_log has no new entries - it stopped tailing 3 days ago. I've had a look through my includes in the main config and I'm missing this file - Include /private/etc/apache2/default.conf

Comment: Hm, on my 10.6 system, there's no `/etc/apache2/default.conf`, so it's probably something custom. However, there's a `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-default.conf` which contains several basic apache2 settings. Maybe that file was copied to `/etc/apache2/default.conf`, or we have different system versions and Apple moved it?

Comment: You say there are no errors when starting apache, yet something is apparently not working anymore. What exactly is it? Can you access any page from the browser? Can you telnet to port 80 (or the port it was configured to listen on)? If so, can you reach any of your ruby code?

Comment: I cannot connect to any page - nor can I telnet.  telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Comment: Simon - I've figured put what files were missing by using sudo apachectl -t - which gave me errors, where /usr/sbin/apachectl start did not give me errors. Could you put your original comment in an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Seems so dumb `sudo apachectl start` doesn't give an error if `sudo apachectl -t` will. I just had this issue, "apache already loaded!" then doesn't work. But -t showed a config error (missing ssl cert). Thanks for the suggestion, much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you start apache via command line (`/usr/sbin/apachectl start`)? If so, does it print any errors? Can you look into `/var/log/apache2/error_log` for any errors? (I'm assuming you're using the apache installation that came with Mac OS X, not some custom build one) Apache's main config file resides at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and references (via lines starting with "Include", at the end of the file) some additional configuration files in `/etc/apache2/extra`. Can you check if any of those are missing?

**edit**: Oh sure, thanks :-) I don't know why `sudo apachectl -t` gave you errors when the non-sudo version did not, though. `apachectl start` should also do what `-t` does. Maybe someone else can shed light on that.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, now I see that I have a typo in httpd.conf. no error logs were created btw when trying to debug

Answer (score 4):

I add the same problem, the `apachectl` service was restarting without error nor log. But the following command finally pointed out what was going wrong:

```
apachectl configtest
```

---

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 611 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Could not open config directory /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sitess.com: No such file or directory
```